# Iterating through particular rows in a csvFile in Python

Tags: python

I have a programming assignment that include csvfiles. So far, I only have a issue with obtaining values from specific rows only, which are the rows that the user wants to look up.

When I got frustrated I just appended each column to a separate list, which is very slow (when the list is printed for test) because each column has hundreds of values.

Question:
The desired rows are the rows whose index[0] == user_input. How can I obtain these particular rows only and ignore the others?

Comment: Can you show some more the code. What is index[]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you an idea:

```
import csv
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',') 
    user_rows = filter(lambda row: row[0] == user_input, reader)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python has the module csv

```
import csv
rows=[]
for row in csv.reader(open('a.csv','r'),delimiter=','):
    if(row[0]==user_input):
        rows.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def filter_csv_by_prefix (csv_path, prefix):
    with open (csv_path, 'r') as f:
        return tuple (filter (lambda line : line.split(',')[0] == prefix, f.readlines ()))

for line in filter_csv_by_prefix ('your_csv_file', 'your_prefix'):
    print (line)
```